# Golang levelDB struct

Tags: struct, go, leveldb

I'm trying to use following DB API: https://godoc.org/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb#
(simple file based key/value DB)

I was able to put and get "key"s into the database.
However, I'm wondering if value can be a struct such as:

```
type Thm struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}
```

Then,

```
var Tmp Thm
Tmp.Name = "Gon"
Tmp.Age = 33

db.Put([]byte("test3"), []byte(Tmp), nil)
```

Right now, the error I'm getting is "cannot covert Tmp (type Thm) to type []byte.

If you have experiences with levelDB, could you help me how normally this will be done?
OR, should I convert struct into byte in order to make this work?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`levelDB` only supports strings/byte arrays as keys and values.  This is actually a pretty smart feature, because it keeps serialization of complex data structures at the application level.  To serialize your `Thm` struct you can try the [gob package](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/) if you don't need applications in other languages to be able to read the values, or protobufs, json, or msgpack if you need the serialized data to be accessible to other languages.

Comment: Thank you. I guess gob package maybe the only option for now :)